# Проблема с template в Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

Всем привет!
В-общем ошибка при копировании шаблона

**An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoneType: None
fatal: [samsung-nb]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "src and dest are required"}**

вот сам playbook

```
- name: Configure webserver with nginx and tls
  hosts: 
  - webserver
  become: True
  vars_files:
    - password.yml
  vars:
    key_file: /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key
    cert_file: /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
    conf_file: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
    server_name: test.io
  tasks:
  - name: install nginx
    apt:
      name: nginx
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 3600
       
  - name: create directory for ssl certificates
    file: 
       path: /etc/nginx/ssl
       state: directory

  - name: copy TLS key
    copy:
       src: files/nginx.key
       dest: "{{ key_file }}"
       owner: root
       mode: 0600
    notify: restart nginx

  - name: copy TLS certificate
    copy: 
       src: files/nginx.crt
       dest: "{{ cert_file }}"
    notify: restart nginx

  - name: copy index.html
    template:
       src: templates/index.html.j2
       dest: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
       mode: 0644

  - name: copy nginx config file
    template: 
       scr: templates/nginx.conf.j2
       dest: "{{ conf_file }}"    
    notify: restart nginx

  - name: enable configuration
    file:
       src: "{{ conf_file }}"
       dest: /etc/nginx/sites_enabled/default
       state: link
    notify: restart nginx

  handlers:
  - name: restart nginx
    service:
       name: nginx
       state: restarted
```

проблема в таске
copy nginx config file

сам шаблон templates/nginx.conf.j2

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name {{ server_name }};
    ssl_certificate {{ cert_file }};
    ssl_certificate_key {{ key_file }};

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Интернет копал ничего найти не смог по этому поводу

Comment: в каком таске ошибка?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не задали в этом таске параметр **src**, вместо него задали несуществующий параметр **scr**.

Comment: Огромное спасибо